# onsenuiのons-lazy-repeatで生成したons-list-item内の値を関数に渡す方法について

Tags: javascript, monaca, html5, onsen-ui

monaca cloudIDEでアプリ開発をしています
ons-lazy-repeatで生成したons-list-itemを列挙するjavascriptを書いているのですが，
このlist-itemをタップした際に実行される関数

```
onclick="js_list2.onClickListItem()
```

に値を２つ以上渡す方法がわかりません(↓のソースコードではindexという値のみ渡すこどができました)
int型のindexに加えてstring型のlist_itemもこの関数に渡したいのですが，どのように渡せばいいでしょうか？

```html
<ons-list modifier="inset">
    <ons-lazy-repeat id="infinite-list"></ons-lazy-repeat>
</ons-list>
```

```js
function show(index){
  document.getElementById("modal").show();
  var page = document.getElementById('navi').topPage;
  var infiniteList = page.querySelector('#infinite-list');

  database.equalTo("category",index)
  .order("createDate",true)
  .fetchAll()
  .then(function(item){
    infiniteList.delegate = {
      createItemContent: function(i) {
        var item_comment = item[i].comment;
        var list_item = item_comment[0];

        for (var j=1; j < item_comment.length; j++){
          if (item_comment[j]==""){
            item_comment[j] = '<br>';
          }
          list_item += item_comment[j];
        }
        return ons.createElement('<ons-list-item data = ' + index + ' onclick="js_list2.onClickListItem(' + index +')" tappable>'+list_item+'</ons-list-item>');
        }
      },
      countItems: function() {
        return 50;
      }
    }
    document.getElementById("modal").hide();
    infiniteList.refresh();
  })
  .catch(function(error){
    document.getElementById("modal").hide();
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

以下のようにシングルクォートで囲めばいけると思います。

```
return ons.createElement('<ons-list-item data="' + index + '" onclick="js_list2.onClickListItem(' + index + ', \'' + list_item + '\')" tappable>' + list_item + '</ons-list-item>');
```